# Facebook Like Button On Web page

Tags: html, asp.net, facebook-like

A client has recently requested social media links on his website. Facebook is my first attempt at this ever. My client does not have a facebook page.

My code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    function renderFbLike() {
        var parent = document.getElementById('fblikediv');
        var child = document.getElementById('fblikeimg');
        parent.removeChild(child);

        //this really works...sort of
        var html2 = "<iframe src=\"http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.jplandman.co.za&send=false&layout=standard&width=450&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=60&appId=258346014244946\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:40px;\" allowTransparency=\"true\"></iframe>";

        document.getElementById('fblikediv').innerHTML = html2;

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="fblikediv">
        <img src="images/fb-like-button.png" id="fblikeimg" onmouseover="return renderFbLike();"></div>
    <p />
</body>
</html>
```

Screen shot: 
[image: Screen shot from facebook]

My question:
The link that says "JPLandman" links to some Facebook page that does not exist. Is there any way to prevent this? What are the possible work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after struggling for a little while for my client I finally found a page that will suffice. They genearate the code. Copy and paste(not my top choice but hey it works as expected)

[AddThis+](http://www.addthis.com/?r=0/)

Answer (score 0):

See if adding this to your head makes any difference!?!

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Some Title"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.jplandman.co.za"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="JP Landman"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Some content"/>
```

Comment: Could you please expand a little on your answer. I added to the head tags but it made no difference?

Comment: These are open graph meta tags, they turn a page into rich object for social graph. Browse here for more [link](http://ogp.me/)

Comment: Btw here is the facebook debugger [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), add above stated meta to site and try debugging and see what you get. Alternatively you can also unlike and like the page again to see what it shows!